# Random space between text?

Tags: css, wordpress, text

Anyone know why there would be space between the first blog post? It always happens, but just to the first post on the blog homepage... (word press)

http://oliveramusic.com/blog/

Not sure if anyone can help... thought I might as well give it a try.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Between each word in the first line of the title "Olivera Winds 2010 ISES Entertainment", there shouldn't be a huge space between each word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're **.post** in your CSS you have the following

```
text-align:justify;
```

The justification of text is what is causing your undesired spaces. You can change that or you can add a text-align property to your **h2** with left, center, or right (depending on your preferences) like so:

```
text-align:left;
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing the wording for a better line wrapping, long text looks better with justify instead of left alignment. That might be just a matter of preference though.